# String replace a dynamic value with php

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I am using cURL to get a form from a site

In the form i am changing the post url with str_replace

```
$data = str_replace('action="'.$url.'"','action="'.get_the_permalink().'?locked=1"', $data);
```

Because this is a multi-language site i also want to change the submit button value. But i cannot use a set value to replace. I need to use php to replace any text in-between the ""

Can anyone assist.

This is currently what i have

```
$data = str_replace('/[^value="](.*)[^"]/','value="a new value"', $data);
```

Comment: `str_replace` doesn't support regex for replacement, You need `preg_replace` instead.

Comment: `str_replace` doesn't work with regular expressions, use `preg_replace` instead.

Comment: do you want to replace a url with another one?

Comment: How would i code a preg_replace to replace the text in-between the value attribute?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it, uusing preg_replace as recommended.

```
$data = preg_replace('/<input type="submit" (.*)value="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<input type="submit" $1value="test"$3>',$data);
```